# Tensorflow on GoogleML with TFrecords: OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

Our Tensorflow trains successfully (but slowly) when we run it locally (on a PC without a GPU). But it fails to train when we send it to GoogleML (single GPU). No change in the code or the data fed in.

The error occurs while reading data from the TFrecords. Some of the relevant code:

```
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(XXXX)
dataset = files.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset, cycle_length=XXXX, sloppy=True, buffer_output_elements=XXXX))

dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(map_func=_parse_transform_function, batch_size=config.batch_size, num_parallel_calls=config.num_parallel_calls))
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.prefetch(config.prefetch)

files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(XXXX)
dataset = files.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset, cycle_length=XXXX, sloppy=True, buffer_output_elements=XXXX))

dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(map_func=_parse_transform_function, batch_size=config.batch_size, num_parallel_calls=config.num_parallel_calls))
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.prefetch(config.prefetch)

training_iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()

...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
    for i in range(config.epochs):
        _image, _landmarks, _height, _width, _size, _kp_true, _short_offsets_true, _long_offsets_true = sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
```

Here is the error we get:

> ERROR 2018-11-28 15:32:55 -0800   service     OutOfRangeError (see above
>   for traceback): End of sequence ERROR 2018-11-28 15:32:55
>   -0800 service          [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,416,416,3], [?,34,5], [?], [?], [?],
>   [?,52,52,11], [?,52,52,22], [?,52,52,40]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Again we did not change the data or the code, so we believe we have no bugs in the Tensorflow code.  Why would the same implementation fail to train in GoogleML?

Answer (score 0):

"OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence" is misleading. It seems to indicate we reached the end of the tfrecords, but that was not the case.

The issue was that an operation in the "_parse_transform_function" (not shown) was using an operation not supported in a GPU.

Solution: Use "with tf.device('/cpu:0'):" around the dataset portion of the code to use the CPU for preprocessing.  The GPU still in use for training.